# How to download files from self hosted VM to VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have python solution which resides in VSTS repository. Using build pipeline and private agent, the source code gets copied to VM.

After executing the python files, output is stored in 3 different files at the source directory level.

I want to download/copy these output files from private hosted VM to VSTS repository.

How can this be achieved?

Thank you

Comment: More details please; are the files you're aiming to move versioned (not necessarily in a SCM, but variant based on conditions in the build) or static? Is the VM internet accessible/firewalled? Or are they artefacts of a build being executed on your VM by a VSTS build agent?

Comment: I have modified the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get something into the repository is by checking it in via source control.

Maybe it's enough for you to just publish these files as a build artifact. You have the option to publish directly to VSTS or to any Windows file share.

If you really want these files in your repository I'd suggest you publish them as build artifacts and check them in with a release pipeline. You could add a new stage in your existing release pipeline or add a new release pipeline that triggers automatically every time your build completes.

Answer (score 0):

You can call git command to add and push changes to repository, for example:

1. Check Allow Scripts to access the OAuth token option
2. Add Command Line task (Tool:git; Arguments: add [file path]; Working folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory))
3. Add command line task (Tool:git; Arguments: commit –m “add build result”; Working folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory))
4. Add command line task (Tool: git; Arguments: push https://test:$(System.AccessToken)@{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_git/{repository} HEAD:master

Related article: [Keep Git repository in sync between VSTS / TFS and Git](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/10/22/keep-git-repository-in-sync-between-vsts-tfs-and-git/)

On the other hand, the better way is publishing the result files as artifact of build through [Publish Build Artifact task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=vsts).